# How were last names created?

Tags: meaning

How were last names created? I've heard that names like Smith and Baker were from their original family occupation. But names like Lee and Ballsack?

Comment: ... I don't think anyone has the last name Ballsack, outside of joke names.

Comment: Very often last names are place names.  My wife's family name is Horvik, from a town in Norway.

Comment: @ScotM: Well, Linkedin also has 2 profiles for the name "Harry Ballsack" and 16 for "Harry Balls", but I'll believe it when I meet someone with a name like this in person and not before :)

Comment: And of course many simply mean "son of"  Macxxx, O'xxxx, xxxxson, xxxsen, Ben xxx, Bin xxx; or "daughter of" xxxdotter.  In England, places named after a person (or not) lend their names to residents thereof: xxxfield, xxxmoor, xxxbridge, xxxdown, xxxmont, xxxpont, ad nauseam.

Comment: It's a little-known fact that all last names are designed and manufactured in a factory south of Montreal. The delivery systems are always in a state of flux, with all kinds of local laws and conventions, but somehow they manage to always deliver the most popular names, every day, worldwide.

Comment: Then there are physical characteristics: Small, Pettit, Whitehead, Shwarzkopf (black head), Brown, Long, Major.  Also many job-names that are obsolete or not widely known (do you know what a fuller does, or a wainwright, or a chandler, or a cooper?)

Comment: @sumelic How about _Balzac_, that close enough?

Comment: Da xxx, De xxx, Di xxx, D'xxx, Duxxx are generally "of" a place name (where do you think Leonardo Da Vinci was  born?  Vinci, of course!)

Comment: Iceland has unique rules about names. Look them up.

Comment: So you take all of these possibilities, multiply by the number of languages, multiply by the multitude of ways names can be mangled in transliteration (think Ellis Island, where thousands and thousands of non-English-speaking immigrants acquired new "English" names)...

Comment: Lee is so simple to find, nobody bothered to mention it. A single google immediately finds http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_(English_surname)

Comment: (That probably explains most of the Xxxxly names as well, except the ones that are attributive adjective "-ly")

Comment: @sumelic I dare say I take umbrage at your remark, good sir. I come from a long line of Ballsacks. We take great pride in our pedigree and our resolve in the face of social adversity that dogs our fine name.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - I don't ever recall meeting someone whose last name ended with "nauseam".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - Yeah, my wife's relatives (last name Horvik) came through Ellis Island with "Horvick" and "Hordvick" and possibly one or two others.  ("Vic", by the way, basically means "village", and is the source (through Old Norse) of the English "vick" suffix for towns and last names.  It is somehow connected with "wicker", though I don't know whether the village or the construction method came first.)

Comment: some surnames are entirely made up.  for instance, this story behind the dutch surname [den beste](http://denbeste.nu/common/biograph.shtml).

Comment: @HotLicks If you mean as in _wickerwork_, they're not connected. That one is purely Germanic and comes from a root meaning ‘bend, warp’ (related to _weak_). The dwelling/farm word _wick_ is originally a loan from Latin and is rare in Norse. It is devilishly similar, however, to Norse _vík_ ‘bay, inlet’, which is also found in many place names (its English form is _-wich_). In fact, I would rather suspect that if your wife's family came from the Hordvik close to Bergen, her _vik_ is the bay, not the farm.

Comment: @HotLicks: as for Nauseam, I haven't either—but one may turn up any minute now; a Ballsack already did!