# Uncommon Term for an Excellent Orator?

Tags: phrases, nouns, idioms

I'm looking for an uncommon term for an excellent orator that doesn’t include adjectives such as “good” or “excellent,” or the noun “orator.” I've *googled* this request but haven't encountered anything compelling.

Comment: D'y'know the phrase "gob full of pebbles outshouting seas" from Tony Harrison's _Them and [uz]_?

Comment: @anemone - no, but I dig the phrase. What does it mean?

Comment: well, I'd hate to push my own interpretation of the poem, but I'd say it refers to an orator. And you asked for _uncommon_ :)

Comment: @anemone - your interpretation is as valid as anyone else's, save the poet's.

Comment: @LittleEva - the 'gob full of pebbles outshouting seas' is a reference to the Greek orator Demosthenes, who trained himself out of a speech impediment by orating alone on the shore with rocks in his mouth to force him to concentrate.

Comment: Most such terms would be based on the name of a famous orator -- Cicero, Williams Jennings Bryan, Edward Everett, Winston Churchill.  Google "famous orators" and you will get more suggestions than you can handle.

Comment: Good point - like Yogi Berra? @Hot Licks - How did you end up at this OP? You following me around? ;-) Check-out my own submission.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want something very unusual and yet historically resonant, you might try *chrysostomic* (that is, "golden-mouthed"). Here's the OED definition of that word:

> **Chrysostomic** *a. rare.* {f. Gr χρυσοστομος golden-mouthed, an epithet applied to favourite orators which became a kind of surname of Dio and John Chrysostom.} Golden-mouthed.
>
> [Example:] **1816** *Month[ly] Rev[iew]* LXXXI 245 By the majesty of his Chrysostomic eloquence.

The quotation from [*The Monthy Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hogCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA245&dq=%22majesty+of+his+Chrysostomic+eloquence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9NgZVdigIpCgyASkn4LwCg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22majesty%20of%20his%20Chrysostomic%20eloquence%22&f=false) (November 1816) runs at greater length as follows:

> Dean Williams, also, with the plasticity of a Roman cardinal, after having subdued by his arguments the puritan chieftain Dr. Reynolds, stalked into the see of Lincoln, which he disdained to illustrate, but, changing his career, took up the seals which Bacon had laid down, and attracted the admiration of the House of Lords by a probity more unfaultering, by a profounder knowlege of the civil law, and by the majesty of his **Chrysostomic** eloquence.

Wikipedia has fairly detailed articles on both [Dio Chrysostom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dio_Chrysostom) and [(Saint) John Chrysostom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Chrysostom).

The OED also has an entry for *chrysostomatical*, which has essentially the same meaning as *chrysostomic* but (to me) doesn't sound as good.

Comment: There he is, finally checking in! Good answer, +1, Sven.

Comment: Also interesting is the, previously unencountered, usage of "illiustrate."

Comment: I think that the intended sense of _illustrate_ is OED's fourth definition (listed as "Now _rare_ or _Obs_.") of the word: "To shed lustre upon; to render illustrious, renowned, or famous; to confer honour or distinction upon." I gather that Williams declined a position in the see of Lincoln, and thus left it, by the absence of his effulgent person, unillustrated.

Comment: That's how I took it.

Comment: Second-place in votes but officially selected! Loved "chrysostomic." Ever encounter the term “stemwinder”, Sven? Checkout my own answer.

Answer (score 26):

**Silver-tongued**

> A tendency to be eloquent and persuasive in speaking.
>   - [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=silvertongue&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox&channel=sb#safe=active&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=define:+silver+tongue)

Comment: I answered an OP just the other day with "silver-tongued." I loved it, but it has only garnered 1 upvote. Oh well ... +1

Comment: I don't know why it's working for you!

Comment: @LittleEva I looked up the question you answered --I think maybe it was the emphasis on "care" in the title of the question that steered people away from your answer...  Otherwise I would have considered it a good fit.

Comment: Not exactly an uncommon term...

Comment: You'll just have to settle for the most points, Chris, but you know I appreciated your offering. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva  Well, why settle for silver when you can go for the gold?

Comment: Ain't it, man! @Chris

Answer (score 11):

[Ciceronian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ciceronian) :

> - in the style of Cicero: characterized by melodious language, clarity, and forcefulness of presentation:
>     *Ciceronian invective.*

*a    [Cicero](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cicero)*:

> - Roman statesman, orator, and philosopher. A major figure in the last years of the Republic, *he is best known for his orations against Catiline and for his mastery of Latin prose*. His later writings introduced Greek philosophy to Rome. (TFD)

- ... [Adam Smith](https://books.google.it/books?id=Nb3LosCYq8cC&pg=PA3&dq=%22a%20cicero%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=n6gZVfzWDsHeU9aogZAP&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20cicero%22&f=false) were particular admirers, but perhaps there was no more devoted Ciceronian, as to both literary style and ideas, than Edmund Burke, *whose thought has been called "a Cicero filtered through the Christian scholastic tradition.*

Comment: Well, you asked for *an uncommon  term*, and yes, as in the example shown it is used to refer to a great orator!!!

Comment: Perhaps softened as a **veritable** Cicero

Comment: Old chick-pea was such a lying lawyer that calling him veritable is all kinds of Ironic.

Comment: What's this, @Oldcat?

Comment: Cicero (means Chickpea) was a advocate who would defend any side of an issue - he offered to defend Catiline just a year before calling him history's greatest monster in his orations.  After his consulship, he flipped political sides several times due to expediency.

Comment: @Oldcat - some things never change, eh?

Answer (score 9):

The one and only correct answer to this question is, quite obviously, **slick whistle-stopper**.

I will now use my prodigious rhetorical skills to prove this point.

Firstly, I did a Google search for that term, which produced the following:

> No results found for "slick whistle-stopper".

And here is the Google Ngram:

> No valid ngrams to plot! Ngrams not found: slick whistle-stopper

Clearly my answer fulfills the OP's desire for an *uncommon* term. No one has ever used this term before. You don't get more uncommon than that.

A whistle-stop, according to Merriam-Webster, is "a brief personal appearance especially by a political candidate usually on the rear platform of a train during the course of a tour." A whistle-stopper, according to thesaurus.com, is a synonym for "candidate" or "politician," but also for "grandstander."

Throughout history, going back to antiquity, the finest orators have always been politicians. Nothing calls to mind the idea of a great orator more than the image of a politician giving a speech from the back of a train. I'm pretty sure even the ancient Greeks did it.

The fact that I can't find "whistle-stopper" in any other online dictionary, again, speaks to the uncommon nature of the word. The word is a gem! A diamond in the rough! Or some other jewel metaphor!

But wait, there's more.

By adding "slick" to "whistle-stopper" -- "slick whistle-stopper" -- we add a top-notch poetical effect, that being the alliteration of S and L. This is guaranteed to call the attention of the literary Illuminati to your prose. Pulitzer Prize, Nobel Prize, PEN/Faulkner, Bram Stoker -- anything is possible.

I'll leave it up to the OP whether she wants to be the first person, ever, to use this beautiful term, or to fall back on something more prosaic, hackneyed, and unimaginative.

Comment: Bravo! LoL, you got my vote, Senator. But I'm easy (not to say, cheap). Let's see how you fare with the cognoscenti, they can be demanding.

Comment: I'm _relatively_ (though admittedly not fully) certain that the Ancient Greeks did not have whistles on their trains. And it's almost ironic that in stating that no one has ever used this term, _you become the first person to do so_, thus removing Eva's opportunity, as per your last paragraph, of doing so.

Comment: That's right! @Janus, I've been hoodwinked by another snake oil salesman, drat!

Comment: If you want to play this game, "slick whistle-stopper" is not a term, it is a phrase.

Comment: You, sir, are quite the slick whistle-stopper.

Comment: Can you believe how much traction you got outta "slick whistle-stopper"? Just the damnedest thing! Thanks for the fun, William.

Answer (score 9):

An excellent orator is a

> [rhetorician](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhetorician).

Since you are asking for an uncommon term, you might enjoy referring to them as a

> [grandiloquent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grandiloquence) rhetorician.

Answer (score 8):

**Raconteur**

> One who tells stories and anecdotes with skill and wit.
>   - [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/raconteur)

Answer (score 7):

> **[doctiloquent](http://wordinfo.info/results/doctiloquent)**
>    A reference to someone *who talks about* a subject which he or she has studied and knows a great deal about

> **[omniloquent](http://wordinfo.info/results/omniloquent)**
>   Being capable of talking about any and all subjects.

> **[suaviloquent](http://onlinedictionary.datasegment.com/word/suaviloquent)**
>   [Latin. *suaviloquens*; *[suavis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suavis)* sweet + *loquens*, p. pr. of *loqui* to speak.]
>   Sweetly speaking; using agreeable speech.

> **[tolutiloquent](http://wordinfo.info/results/tolutiloquent)**
>    Speaking characterized by fluency or glibness of utterance; rapid and ready of speech; fluency
>   From Latin *[tolutim](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2060004)*, "trotting along"; "on a (full) trot".

Answer (score 6):

> **[melliloquent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/melliloquent)** (literally *honey-tongued*)
>   *Speaking sweetly or harmoniously*.
>   Latin *mel*, *mellis* honey + *loquens* speaking, present participle of *loqui* to speak.

Comment: +1, though for accuracy, it is literally _honey-speaking_, rather than _honey-tongued_.

Comment: Thanks, Mari-Lou, for the great offerings. "Melliloquent" was my second most favoritest! But Sven beat you out with "chrysostomic".  :-)

Answer (score 5):

***[Rhetorical magician](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/226975/obama-rhetorical-magician-rich-lowry)***:

> *[rhetorical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rhetorical)*
>
> adjective
>
> 1 Relating to or concerned with the art of rhetoric:
>
> *[magician](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/magician)*
>
> noun
>
> 1.0 A person with magical powers.
>
> 1.1 A conjuror.
>
> 1.2 *informal* A person with exceptional skill in a particular area.

The art of rhetoric tends to be a black box to the masses, who experience the impact of great oratory as magic. From page 222 of Gary A. Olson's *[Rhetoric and Composition as Intellectual Work](https://books.google.com/books?id=3FSPzywhx80C&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=rhetorical%20magician&source=bl&ots=3nwE2eZ4uP&sig=NA-GJOrXM8N60RRAaksK13JwxMk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1KsZVYiyNOq1sASRhIKgCw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=rhetorical%20magician&f=false)*:

> All rhetoric can be understood, then, to have a magical component, and
>   all magic--dependent as it is on spells--is rhetorical. Thus, we can
>   posit the term *magic-rhetoric* as an indicator of their inseparability.

Comment: This was phantastic and poetic. Thank you for playing.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to believe no one's mentioned this term yet. You could also refer to such a person as you've described as a **cunning linguist**.

Comment: @LittleEva One of these days I'm going to change my name back to its "normal" one. Just as soon as I stop getting a laugh out of the [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233321/how-were-last-names-created) that inspired this current name.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the adjective ***Demosthenic***, derived from the famous historical figure *Demosthenes* who is considered the greatest orator of antiquity. (and perhaps all time; even Cicero presents Demosthenes as the greatest orator of all time in *De Optimo*.)

> Of or relating to Demosthenes or his oratory; typical of or resembling Demosthenes or his speeches, esp. in being lucid, persuasive, or single-minded of purpose.
>
> - 2007     P. Parsons *City Sharp-nosed Fish* ix. 146     The well-educated man could write Homeric verses, or a **Demosthenic speech**, in near-perfect imitation of the original language.
>
> [OED]

*Demosthenian* and *Demosthenical* are mentioned as the earlier synonyms.

I believe it won't get any better than this; otherwise Demosthenes would turn over in his grave and might even come back for one last speech! Here is an excerpt about Demosthenes:

> Demosthenes was a Greek orator, speech-writer, and politician. He was known as a great champion of democracy and an advocate of the right of Greece to exist as a separate nation from Macedonia.
>
> Other orators who were contemporaries of Demosthenes regarded him as a great orator. According to Longinus, Demosthenes "perfected to the utmost the tone of lofty speech, living passions, copiousness, readiness, speed”, Cicero acclaimed him as "the perfect orator" who lacked nothing, and Quintilian described him as setting a standard for all orators.
>
> [acsu.buffalo.edu](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/%7Educhan/new_history/ancient_history/demosthenes.html)

Comment: Excellent suggestion, ermanen. I must read his speeches, alas, in translation. +1

Comment: @LittleEva: You are welcome. You can consider [this book](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Demosthenes_Speeches_1_17.html?id=Wu9Gk62O2DgC) that contains translations of all the surviving speeches of Demosthenes.

Answer (score 2):

Rather colloquial, but **Speech maven** would do the job: Webster's [Maven](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maven):

> Synonyms:
>       ace, adept, artist, authority, cognoscente, connoisseur, crackerjack (also crackajack), dab [chiefly British], dab hand [chiefly British], fiend, geek, guru, hand, hotshot, maestro, master, expert (also mavin), meister, past master, proficient, scholar, shark, sharp, virtuoso, whiz, wizard

Comment: +1, yes, I'm known in certain (confused) quarters as a :speech-maven," myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***elocutionist*** also. *OED* defines as: one who practices the art of elocution; a proficient in the art of elocution. But, it is also defined as:

> a public speaker trained in voice production and gesture and delivery - [*TFD*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elocutionist)

Elocutionists combine elocutionary and oratory skills; and they emerged out of the elocution movement in 19th century in US.

> Elocutionist was the name given to both those who performed orations themselves and those who taught others how to perform. These US specialists in oral presentation called themselves elocutionists, following the already established elocution movement in the United Kingdom.
>
> [[acsu.buffalo.edu]](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~duchan/new_history/hist19c/elocution.html)

The following excerpt describes a great orator and explains the difference between an elocutionist and an orator by comparing Lincoln's and Everett's speech.

> [image]
>   [image]
>
> <sub>*Lincoln in His Own Time: A Biographical Chronicle of His Life, Drawn from Recollections, Interviews, and Memoirs by Family, Friends, and Associates (Writers in Their Own Time)* by Harold K. Bush Jr. (2011)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**A Demosthene**

This antonomasia is quite rare in french. It is certainly uncommon in english.

Comment: @LittleEva - Are you asking for *the negative proof*?

Comment: No, I was just teasing. What I was requesting was for you to convince me of your offering's validity, with linked references to established authorities, etymological arcana, examples of usage, etc. I'm asking you to grow your answer. I'm asking a lot, I know. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If something informal works for you, I really like **gift of the gab**, as in "she has the gift of the gab".

Link: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the-gift-of-the-gab

Answer (score 1):

I suppose  *orator* is not the first word that springs to mind when talking about a . . . public speaker. But if I wanted something a bit harder I might go with *rhetor*. It certainly brings to mind classical figures like Cicero without mentioning them directly.

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone ever encounter the term “*stemwinder*”?**

> The term dates back to the middle of the 19th century, when the stem-winding watch came into vogue. The newfangled timepiece was a vast improvement over its predecessor, the key-wound watch, because the mechanism for setting it was a stem actually attached to the watch, rather than a key that was easily and frequently misplaced. This technological advance was so widely appreciated that, by the end of the 1800s, the term *stemwinder* had taken on the figurative meaning of "excellent" or "outstanding," or, as the Oxford English Dictionary puts it, "*a person or thing that is first rate*. …"
>
> Even early on, ***the phrase was used to describe great orators***. Michael Quinion of World Wide Words found a reference dating to 1880, in the Daily Gazette of Colorado Springs: "Dr. Reynolds will have some big stories to tell when he returns from Europe. He will then be, more than ever, the great '*stem-winder*' of the west." But the word had myriad other applications. Jack London, in his 1909 novel Martin Eden, used the term to describe a knockout headache: "Gee, but it's a *stem-winder*," one character says. "Can hardly see." And in the novel *Bunch Grass*, published in 1913, author Horace Annesley Vachell's characters toast the man who convinced them it was better to drink whisky than water:
>
> "The Perfessor's a *stem-winder*, an' no mistake," said Pete. "Let's drink his health — onst." They did so — twice.
>
> These days, of course, "*stemwinder*" is no longer used to describe headaches or professors; although it's not clear why the wider usage fell out of favor, the term is used exclusively to describe an excellent speech. see Slate [**stemwinder**](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2004/08/whats_a_stemwinder.html)

Comment: Actually, I think common usage (including the examples you give) implies a sort of speaking style that stirs up the crowd -- not merely eloquent and mellifluous, but exciting and rousing.

Comment: Yes, @Hot Licks, except I don't think there is anymore *common usage* of the term, having personally never encountered outside of my search results.

Comment: I've heard "stemwinder" many times.  And a convenient attribute of the word is that the most common context ("That was a real stemwinder!") is understandable even if someone has never heard the word before.

Answer (score 0):

"oratissimo" (since ScotM likes it)

Comment: @LittleEva, are you asking me whether "oratissimo" is a real word?  Yes, it is, as of now.

Comment: @LittleEva, I refer you to your original question.  The meaning is the meaning you asked for.

Comment: That's a neat trick. Are you, by any chance, the Wizard of ELU? +1 for your panache, or should I say, pennacchio?

Comment: Paid in full. The etymology should start here with a short explanation of how this neologism gathered its parts.

Comment: Thanks for playing, Greg. I just want you to know that I've "test-driven" your creation. The police keep pulling me over and asking for my documents. I keep pointing to you.